# SD Card and Sony Xperia E3

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, sony-xperia

I recently purchased a 16gb SanDisk SDHC card by mistake (the website said it was a normal SD card, not SDHC.) I put the card in and it seems to be working fine, but I was curious if there could be any damage to the phone or to the data I save to it if the phone isn't compatible? The phone description says it takes up to a 16gb SD card, but doesn't support SDHC cards... and I can't find 16gb versions of the SD card.

Comment: This is most likely just imprecise terminology in the specification, perhaps because Sony figured that a typical layperson wouldn't know what SDHC is. In reality, the "SD" standard [cannot exceed 2 GB in size](https://www.sdcard.org/developers/overview/capacity/), so a 16 GB "SD" card is an impossibility. It has to be SDHC.

Answer (score 0):

**NO,It will not harm your phone**

Since, operating speed of SD is less than SDHC.Data transfer will occur at same rate which is supported by your mobile phone.
So it will not harm your phone.